# How to query HSM slot for value "key handle" using (known) value "key label"

Tags: python, pkcs#11, hsm, cryptoki

Need to query HSM (in Python) using known values HSM "slot #", "key label" to obtain (unknown value) "key handle".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pkcs11.Session.get_key()](https://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pkcs11.Session.get_key) to get unique object in HSM by label.

An example to get an AES key with label "Label":

```
with token.open(user_pin='1234', rw=True) as session:
    key = session.get_key(object_class=ObjectClass.SECRET_KEY, key_type=KeyType.AES, label="Label")
```

Use [pkcs11.Session.get_objects()](https://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pkcs11.Session.get_objects) for more complex searches.

Note: You do not need the "key handle" value at all as you can perform operations using returned `key` object.

Good luck!

Comment: Now why did I not see these references while searching the SAME documentation??? :) Nothing like a fresh set of eyes. Tremendous thanks! I will update post as soon as I get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You put me on the right track. I ended up using c_find_objects_ex to grab the key handle and used slice to chop off the trailing "L" in the output. Thanks!